# is Apple dropping support for 32-bit devices?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

Development environment is Visual Studio, Mac (formerly Xamarin).  Just updated like 2 weeks ago.

I have a new app up and running in the simulator.  It was working in pretty much every device until I added in the "Using" for JSON parsing.

Essentially, this is the only thing I added:

```
var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(YOUR_URL_HERE);
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "application/JSON";
request.BeginGetResponse(ResponseComplete, request);
```

That is, I had the app running on my trusty iPhone 5C testing device.  Then I added in some new stuff to talk to my server, and it no longer works on that device.  It launches and disappears instantly.

So I changed the Simulator to run an older iPhone 5 version.  Crashes there too.  But there I can see the log telling me that the Boostrap failed.

Doing some searching tells me that 32-bit devices will no longer be supported.

This seems strange to me.  The app compiles fine.  And it is assumed that it will work on any device running 10.3.  It turns out that does not appear to be true.

Am I missing something?  Is there something I need to check for?  Do I need to change my target devices to disallow older 32-bit iPhones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, see https://9to5mac.com/2017/06/04/32-bit-apps-ios-11/

"The thing is ahead of iOS 11, 32-bit applications will stop appearing in App Store search results . This is the latest piece of evidence that suggests iOS 11 will drop support altogether for 32-bit applications when it’s unveiled next week to developers and to the general public later this fall."

Comment: Ok, so what you're saying is that this one component may be jumping the gun and dropping support, even though the rest of the build is letting it go?  Meaning that the app will compile unaware that that one component will fail.

Comment: @durbnpoisn Here is the Apple oficial anouncement:https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=06282017a

Comment: I'm giving you credit for the answer, even though you only provided a link.  It was still better than what I had found on my own.  So thanks for that.